Center xaxis at 0 for values between 270 and 90 degrees
I have a set of data centered at 0, spanning from 90 to 270 degrees. When I make a scatter plot, I want it also to be center at 0 at the Cartesian plane.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt 

ang = np.array([0, 90, 270])
radi = [1, 2, 3]

plt.scatter(ang, radi)

Coverting the data to the -180 to 180 interval, and redefining the x-axis labels:
test = -1*(np.array(ang)+180)%360 - 180

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

labels = [90, 0, 270]
ax.scatter(test, radi)

plt.xticks(np.sort(test), labels, rotation='vertical')

plt.show()

I get the desired visualization. Is there a better way of doing this though?

Do you mean that you want to convert the points from polar to cartesian coordinates and then plot them?

Or, if you tell us what plt is, there might be a way to plot the points given in polar coordinates directly.

Not convert them to Cartesian. Instead, I would like to plot them as polar but 90 deg on the left, 0 at the center and 360 on the right rather than 0, 90, 360.

Okay, so what is plt? Assuming it's matplotlib, have you seen https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_demo.html?

plt and np defined in the question now. Yes, I've checked it out. The data represents whether a particle moves towards (0 deg) or opposite (180 deg) a receptor. The latter is defined between [90, 180 and 270] degrees, so the peak 'opposite' to the receptor lies naturally at the center when plotted in Cartesian. I want to show the same for the ones 'towards' the receptor.

The problem is, you are trying to plot polar coordinates (angle and radii) as cartesian (x and y). You can make a polar plot like this:
ang = np.array([0, 90, 270])
radi = np.array([1, 2, 3])

theta = ang * np.pi / 180

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')
ax.scatter(theta, radi)
plt.show()

Alternatively, you can use the formula to convert polar to cartesian: x = radius * cos(theta) and y = radius *  sin(theta).
x = radi * np.cos(theta)
y = radi * np.sin(theta)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlim(-4, 4)
plt.ylim(-4, 4)
plt.show()


If you want to display 90 at the left and 270 at the right, the polar plot can be rotated by:
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")


